# How can I cleanly programatically add images to the clipboard and paste them?

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, clipboard, registerhotkey

i have a global registered hotkey which works fine, inside this hotkey is the following code:

```
        {
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(Properties.Resources.cookie);
            SendKeys.SendWait("^v");
        }
```

It adds the cookie image to my clipboard and pastes it in which ever window is activated. However it only works properly the first time and pastes the image.

The second time i get:
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

and this pops up:

[image]

However this only pops up if the program has this option, otherwise nothing happens (but i still get the exception error).

But if i manually press ctrl+V... it works every time :S

Answer (score 0):

The `Clipboard` class has a different method that might work better for you:

```
Clipboard.SetImage(...);
```

When setting `DataObject` only, you can also specify the type of the object. This would also be a viable option, that probably works the same exact way, but using the appropriate method seems.. well.. more appropriate.

Another important note:

`Clipboard` method's only work on "Single Apartment" threads, so if you're not performing the action on the UI thread, you should make sure to set the thread's state to `STA`.

Comment: I just noticed that the uncompressed bitmap version that is in the clipboard is 10times bigger. Is it possible to save the actual png to the clipboard instead of the image data?

Comment: You could try using some Windows API, but it would probably work as the `Clipboard.SetImage` method. When you say 10 times bigger, you mean in width and height?

Comment: no kb, if using a clipboard viewer (http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-clipboard-manager-viewer) load the image to the clipboard and then save the image from the clipboard viewer its 200k instead of 20k. i need it as small as possible... (because images in clipboard are decompressed?). BTW: SetImage gives the same result.

Comment: First thing I would try is to resave the data into an `Image` or `Bitmap` object, using these and these image settings to choose resolution, etc, and then use that object with that `Clipboard.SetImage` method.

Comment: Try using the `Clipboard.Clear` method before setting anything into it.